# Firebase App Distribution - Update existing IPA for new UDID

Tags: provisioning-profile, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution, udid, firebase-app-distribution

I am new to all this, but I am assuming the IPA for Ad-Hoc through Firebase App Distribution contains the provision profile with allowed device UDIDs. If then I want to add a new device, I need to update the profile, rebuild and re-upload the IPA. Let's assume the app hasn't changed aside from the added UDID, ie same release

I have the user invited to the existing release but because I didn't know their UDID until after the invite was accepted I now have to rebuild the IPA. If I then upload the rebuilt IPA with the additional UDID to Firebase Console for app distribution does this automatically replace the existing release and email only this user that its now ready from download?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will show up as a new release and will be re-distributed to all the testers you have in the group. Ideally it's best to just distribute to the one new tester whose UDID you just added.